# Where to put test classes?

Tags: testing, junit, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-fragment

When testing Eclipse RCP plugins, it is good practice to have all test classes and resources live in a dedicated (test) fragment.
This way all classes in the host plugin can be accessed, no matter if those packages are actually exported or not.

But what if I have a common test infrastructure, that is used by many plugins?

I cannot put this into a fragment, since I cannot reuse classes inside a fragment somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fragment does not *exist* at runtime. It is *merged* with its `Fragment-Host`.

You either need to place the code in a regular bundle/plug-in, or use a *poxy* bundle that exposes the classes of the fragment to be accessible from other fragments or bundles. For example:

**Host**

```
Bundle-SymbolicName: org.example.test.util
Eclipse-ExtensibleAPI: true
```

**Fragment**

```
Bundle-SymbolicName: org.example.test.util.impl
Export-Package: org.example.test.util.impl
Fragment-Host: org.example.test.util
```

However, the latter approach uses the Eclipse-specific `Extensible-API` header that is only understood by the Equinox OSGi implementation.

Therefore, my recommendation would be to leave the actual test classes in a fragment that corresponds to the bundle-under-test and put the reusable test helpers in a dedicated bundle.